# How to draw path with MapKit in real time (iOS7+)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay, mkpolyline

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a path with MapKit given an array of location (lat/long) points. I think I need to use MKPolyline and MKOverlayRenderer. I can only seem to find information on MKRoute and MKDirections, but this is not what I need.

To start with I will have one point. Every 10 seconds or so another point will be added. How can I draw a line on a map in real time given an array of points, where the array grows over time?

This is all I have so far:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *route = overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *routeRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:route];
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        return routeRenderer;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like MKAnnotation (http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial) or drawing the lines with delay?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with `MKPolyline` and `MKPolylineRenderer` as you have, but also look into `-[MKOverlayRenderer setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:]` and the associated conversion routines to translate `MKMapRect` to `CGRect` (if necessary) and you should be able to force a screen refresh upon receipt of new data.